# c# LINQ to XML Query Expression for elemennt exhist?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, element

```
<channel>
        <title>Best Web Gallery - Flash + CSS Gallery</title>
        <link>http://bestwebgallery.com</link>
        <description>Featuring the world best web design</description>
        <pubDate>09 Dec 2009</pubDate>    
        <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=2.3.2</generator>
        <language>en</language>
</channel>   


<channel>
        <title>Best Web Gallery - Flash + CSS Gallery</title>
        <link>http://bestwebgallery.com</link>
        <description>Featuring the world best web design</description>

            // pubDate missing

        <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=2.3.2</generator>
        <language>en</language>
</channel>




   XDocument rssFeed = XDocument.Load(url);

                    var feedResources = from details in rssFeed.Descendants("channel")
                                    select new feedResource
                                    {
                                         Title = details.Element("title").Value,
                                         Host = details.Element("link").Value,
                                         Description = details.Element("description").Value,  

                                         PublishedOn = DateTime.Parse(details.Element("pubDate").Value), 
                                         Generator = details.Element("generator").Value,
                                         Language = details.Element("language").Value
                                    };
```

How can We check here before trying to get Element "pubDate " or others, because if not checked, throws null reference exception ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Parse` etc; xml typically uses different string representations than it accepts; just cast (note no `.Value`):

```
select new FeedResource
{
    Title = (string)details.Element("title"),
    Host = (string)details.Element("link"),
    Description = (string)details.Element("description"),
    PublishedOn = (DateTime?)details.Element("pubDate"),
    Generator = (string)details.Element("generator"),
    Language = (string)details.Element("language")
}
```

`XElement` has conversion operators to do all the work, returning appropriate values.

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference is to add two extension methods to XElement:

```
public static string ValueOrDefault(this XElement xml)
{
    if (xml == null) return null;   // or String.Empty, if you prefer
    return xml.Value
}

public static string ValueOrDefault(this XElement xml, string defaultValue)
{
    if (xml == null) return defaultValue;
    return xml.Value
}
```

Now your code will look something like:

```
select new feedResource
{
     Title = details.Element("title").ValueOrDefault(),
     Host = details.Element("link").ValueOrDefault(),
     Description = details.Element("description").ValueOrDefault(),  

     PublishedOn = DateTime.Parse(details.Element("pubDate").ValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now.ToString())), 
     Generator = details.Element("generator").ValueOrDefault(),
     Language = details.Element("language").ValueOrDefault()
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the line:

```
PublishedOn = DateTime.Parse(details.Element("pubDate").Value),
```

for:

```
PublishedOn = details.Element("pubDate") != null? DateTime.Parse(details.Element("pubDate").Value) : DateTime.Now,
```

you can change the DateTime.Now for whatever you want